# How can I configure ripgrep to always search from my home directory?

Tags: ripgrep

How can I configure my `~/.ripgreprc` glob(s) to always search from the home directory regardless of where I run `rg` from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't configure ripgrep to do that, and it would be a bad idea to do that if you could, but you can make a shell function to do what you want.

Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
function rgh()
{
    rg "$@" ~/
}
```

Then you just `rgh whatever` and it will expand to `rg whatever ~/`.

(I chose `rgh` for "ripgrep home" but you can call it whatever you want.)